# Moving items between listboxes in python

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I'm brand new to python, with only a little VBA experience behind me. I'm trying to create a simple card tracking program using tkinter. I want to be able to move the cards between two listboxes so they can first be discarded and then returned to the deck. I have got the basics working, with two listboxes set up and two buttons that move cards between them; however, I am having trouble doing this for a selected card from the listboxes. (At the moment it is just set up to move the first value.)

I have searched for solutions but with next to no programming experience I haven't been able to interpret any of the variety of solutions already out there to my code. From what I've read, it seems like there is some incompatibility between the format the listbox returns and using the index value. I've found various bits of advice for how to convert one into the other but failed to make it work for myself!

Many thanks in advance for your help!

```
 from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Twilight Struggle Card Counter")
root.geometry("1400x600")

#Define named cards
KOH = "King of Hearts"
QOD = "Queen of Diamonds"

#Compile card lists
Draw = [KOH,QOD,3,4,5,6]
Discard = []

#Create Draw listbox
Drawbox = Listbox(root,width=20)
Drawbox.pack(pady=15)

#Create Discard listbox
Discardbox = Listbox(root,width=20)
Discardbox.pack(pady=20)

#Add lists to listbox
for item in Draw:
    Drawbox.insert(END, item)

for item in Discard:
    Discardbox.insert(END, item)

#need to find a way to convert listbox value to integer
a = Drawbox.index(ACTIVE)
b = Discardbox.index(ACTIVE)

#Discard button
def discard():
    Discard.append(Draw.pop(a))
    Drawbox.delete(0, END)  #clear listbox
    for item in Draw:
        Drawbox.insert(END, item)
    Discardbox.delete(0, END)
    for item in Discard:
        Discardbox.insert(END, item)
    
    print("Draw", Draw, "Discard", Discard)
    
Discard_Button = Button(root,text="Discard", command=discard)
Discard_Button.pack(pady=10)

#Add button
def Add():
    Draw.append(Discard.pop(b))
    Discardbox.delete(0, END)  #clear listbox
    for item in Discard:
        Discardbox.insert(END, item)
    Drawbox.delete(0, END)
    for item in Draw:
        Drawbox.insert(END, item)
    
    print("Draw", Draw, "Discard", Discard)
    
Add_Button = Button(root,text="Add", command=Add)
Add_Button.pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `curselection` method to get the currently selected items. It will return a list, so you'll need to get the index of the selected item out of the list.

The solution would look something like this:

```
def discard():
    selection = Drawbox.curselection()
    if selection:
        index = selection[0]
        card = Draw.pop(index)
        Discard.append(card)
        Drawbox.delete(index)
        Discardbox.insert("end", card)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That's really helpful. It's working now.